# jenkins input step input dialogue box not showing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to add an input step to my jenkins pipeline. I can see the input step message in the console output, but not showing as dialogue when mouse over the stage view.

Not sure what I have done wrong or missing. I have also tried just using input with a message inside steps, which also only shows the message in the console output. I am running on jenkins 2.259 from docker.  Any suggestions please?

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            input{
                message "Should we continue?"
                ok "Yes, we should."
                submitter "alice,bob"
                parameters {
                    string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
                }
            }
            steps {
               echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

enter image description here [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed broken since version 2.16 of the stage view plugin. You can temporarily fix this by downgrading the plugin to version 2.15.

There's an issue open for this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63892